# Web API Root Element

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I tried this code:

WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

In my API Controller code:

```
    [Route("fetch")]
    public IEnumerable<S1.Location> Get()
    {
        var location = _locationService.GetAll();
        var loList = new List<S1.Location>();
        foreach (Location loc in location)
        {
            var lo = new S1.Location()
            {
                Id = loc.ID.ToString(),
                Title = loc.Title
            };
            loList.Add(lo);
        }
        return loList;
    }
```

And Location class defines this:

```
[XmlRoot("MyLocation")]
public class Location
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I was expecting a result of

```
<MyLocation>
    <Location Id="3" Title="Causeway Bay1"/>
    <Location Id="5" Title="Kowloon Bay"/>
    <Location Id="6" Title="Kowloon Bay"/>
</Location>
```

but receiving a

```
<ArrayOfLocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Location Id="3" Title="Causeway Bay1"/>
    <Location Id="5" Title="Kowloon Bay"/>
    <Location Id="6" Title="Kowloon Bay"/>
</Location>
```

Why the root element doesn't change?

Comment: try to set `[XmlType("MyLocation")]` instead of `[XmlRoot("MyLocation")]`

Comment: also did that, still the ArrayOfLocation still displayed in the result.

Comment: Instead of having the ArrayOfLocation to be the root, I am expecting it to be MyLocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change use a custom class that inherits from the List

```
 [XmlType("MyLocation")]
        public class MyLocation:List<Location>
        {

        }
```

and use it in your get method

```
 public MyLocation Get()
    {
        var location = _locationService.GetAll();
        var loList = new MyLocation();
        foreach (Location loc in location)
        {
            var lo = new S1.Location()
            {
                Id = loc.ID.ToString(),
                Title = loc.Title
            };
            loList.Add(lo);
        }
        return loList;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but instead of attribute, the Id and Title became an Element. Though I haven't noticed the Root Element.

Comment: so what's the issue with this ?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel, Jeric wants `Id` and `Title` to be attributes, not elements

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Tried it also, the arrayofmylocation is still the root.

Comment: this is normal since you are returning the .net type try my updated answer

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel This may help. Correct me if I'm wrong, using DataContractSerializer doesn't have a way to set some of my properties to be an attribute of an XML?

Comment: yes that's right check  my updated answer just use xmlattribute  on your properties

Comment: Exactly ... I believe those xmlsns attribute won't be remove right. Finally, I should've create another class that will handle those list.